# jQuery set attribute on newly generated item

Tags: jquery, dom, insert

I'm getting the select html and want to give it a new name, this is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
var sel = $("#rmFilesListSelect").html();
$(sel).attr({name: "item_files[fid-123]"});
$("#someTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + sel + "</td></tr>");
```

However, this does not work as I would expect it. Instead it inserts the old id from #rmFilesListSelect. What am I missing here?

EDIT:
I have ended up using a combination of several comments (including outerHTML() from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259788/1231450, linked by bitfiddler)

```
var sel = $("#rmFilesListSelect").clone();
$(sel).attr({name: "item_files[fid-123]"});
$("#someTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + $(sel).outerHTML() + "</td></tr>");
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var sel = $("#rmFilesListSelect").html();
$(sel).wrapAll("<tr><td><div id='item_files[fid-123]'></div></td></tr>");
$("#someTable tbody").append("sel");
```

EDIT:
And somethin like this?

```
var sel = $("#rmFilesListSelect").clone();
$(sel).attr({id: 'new_id', name: 'new_name'});
$("#someTable tbody").append(sel);
```

Comment: Good idea and +1 for wrapAll but I need to change the select id and name (not the div around it).

Comment: I do a new try, please give a look

Comment: I've used your and bitfiddler comments and have updated my question in order to reflect the code that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line set the variable sel to the html not the object. In line 2 your treat it like an object and try to set it's name attribute. I think you need to change line 1 to:

```
var sel = $("#rmFilesListSelect");
```

and line 3 to:

```
$("#someTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + sel.html() + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: This comes close but inserts the options instead of the whole select element.

Comment: That what the html() function does - it gets the inner html for the object. You want the outer html. Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: Additional to my last comment, you could just use the Javascript native outerHTML attribute like this: `$("#someTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + sel.outerHTML + "</td></tr>");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var sel = $("#rmFilesListSelect").html();
// Above line gives the entire html of rmFilesListSelect element
// So better, you can select an element from that html to set the name as used like below line
$(sel).attr("name", "item_files[fid-123]") ;
$("#someTable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + sel + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Where is the dofference to my code? The select still has the old id/name.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:
js

```
var jquery_selector = $("#test");
jquery_selector.attr("data-id", "data-test");
var input_value = jquery_selector.data("id"); //got value of extended data attribute
jquery_selector.append('<input type="text" value="' + input_value + '"/>');
jquery_selector.append(jquery_selector.html());
```

html

```
<div id="test">some text</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZU4BD/2/

Hope it will help.